# Is it possible to have a toolbar in nvim or an nvim GUI? Other workarounds for remembering obscure keybindings?

Tags: neovim

In gvim it is possible to get plugin-specific toolbars (see screenshot attached). Is something like this possible in nvim? Is there a GUI for nvim in which it is possible?

From Googling, the only thing I've been able to find is that this is an unpopular question to ask. Apparently using a toolbar is un-vim. I don't understand this. Toolbars do not necessarily involve using a mouse. They are a convenient way to get a quick list of keyboard shortcuts for plugins that may not be frequently used.

For example, sometimes I code in R and I use the excellent Nvim-R plugin. However, I can go for months at a time between R coding sessions, so I naturally forget some of the keybindings. Having a menu entry in a toolbar is a really easy way to jog my memory:
[image]
I would certainly be open to non-toolbar ways to achieve the same thing. Searching through the help each time is not efficient. Quickly outputting a list of keybindings in a side-bar window would be a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

I built a plugin for this :)

It’s called [popsikey](https://github.com/benknoble/popsikey): you define a prefix mapping, and a list of mappings under that prefix. When you type the prefix, all the mappings are presented in a navigable popup. You can then hit the actual mapping key, or navigate with j/k/enter/escape.

If popups aren’t supported, you just get all the mappings defined under the prefix. (Though the code uses features from fairly recent vim, like lambdas and method chaining, so it seems unlikely that popups aren’t supported if the plugin loads without error. Also, I haven’t tested with neovim and I don’t know what its popup API looks like.)

There are some slight limitations due to the RHS of maps being stringly-typed, but it does enough to be useful for simple things, and [examples](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/plugin/leader.vim) look fairly declarative.

Here's a screenshot with some ALE (`<leader>a`) commands mapped for ease-of-access:

[image]

Comment: A screenshot is a must for such a plugin.

Comment: @eyalkarni how's that? I didn't crop it, but

Comment: it looks nice indeed

Comment: The #{k:v} you use isn't compatible with neovim probably.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble your plugin looks great. Is it designed for neovim, or for vim?

Comment: @evencoil I built it with vim in mind, so I suspect there are some compatibility issues. If anyone has neovim and the time to identify the issues, I would be happy to start fixing them. (File ‘em over at GitHub, please.)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Ok, I guess it doesn't really fix my problem then since with Vim I already have a solution using a GUI (Gvim in this case) and a toolbar. This seems to be a Neovim specific issue.

Comment: Yeh, Literal dicts are about to be introduced. I am waiting for this to happen. https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/12741

Answer (score 2):

First things first, Neovim itself is a server process (that also has a builtin fallback TUI, but it's not of interest here), which communicates with one (or several) frontend UI applications.

Now, all VimScript runs on "the server", while all the UI is drawn by "the frontend". Of course, there's an open inter-process communication channel between them, and you can even send messages from within VimScript, however, Neovim neither defines specific API for creating menus and toolbars, nor even requires "the frontend" to have them at all.

And so, it's theoretically possible, but in practice you just can't.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Is it correct to say that this is a consequence of the design of NeoVim relative to Vim?